# PlayWright can't take screenshot - page closed

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, playwright

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a failed testcase using `Jest` and `PlayWright`, the handling function is defined in a custom environment as seen below

```
const PlaywrightEnvironment = require('jest-playwright-preset/lib/PlaywrightEnvironment')
    .default

class CustomEnvironment extends PlaywrightEnvironment {
    async setup() {
        await super.setup()
    }

    async teardown() {
        await super.teardown()
    }

    async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
        if (event.name === 'test_done' && event.test.errors.length > 0) {
            const parentName = event.test.parent.name.replace(/\W/g, '-')
            const specName = event.test.name.replace(/\W/g, '-')

            await this.global.page.screenshot({
                path: `screenshots/${parentName}_${specName}.png`,
            })
        }
    }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

However, I am closing the pages after each test..

```
afterEach(async () => {
    await page.close();
});
```

This leads to the `page` being closed before the screenshot is captured

> Test suite failed to run

```
page.screenshot: Target page, context or browser has been closedError:

  18 |             const specName = event.test.name.replace(/\W/g, '-')
  19 |
> 20 |             await this.global.page.screenshot({
     |                                    ^
  21 |                 path: `screenshots/${parentName}_${specName}.png`,
  22 |             })
  23 |         }
```

Is there a way to either pass the event to the `afterEach` so that it doesn't close if an error occurred or a way to take the screenshot more synchronously so that `afterEach` does not get executed before the screenshot is taken, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are deliberate specialized cases you may want to use page.close() in a custom fixture/config but I'm wouldn't say that's the case for you based on what you're trying to do. By default, the browser/context will close automatically after each test, and will therefore also close the page being tested. You can see the default teardown [here](https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright/blob/fa5464bbc9a23c9658d2cee6071c51765241b1e3/src/PlaywrightEnvironment.ts#L349).

Removing your afterEach method should resolve the issue. :)

Other notable features:

- Checkout [Playwright-Test](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test#modify-context-options-for-a-single-test) to see how custom config/fixtures can help you make consistent test environments, (ie. if you wanted some environments to take screenshots `only-on-failure` but not others.
- Playwright also supports [page object models](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) -- a feature that makes your tests much more readable and maintainable. I also have an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095616/implementing-custom-fixtures-using-config-with-new-playwright-0-1101) that you can reference for Page Object Models with the new version of Playwright, if this helps.

Comment: I am trying to only take the screenshot on failure. That's why I asked if there is a way to pass the information that the test failed to the `afterEach`.

Comment: so the `afterEach -> page.close()` is redundant? I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: yeah it turned out the `page.close()` was completely redundant - PlayWright handles it automatically. If you edit your answer so that it says that, I'll mark it as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @Dropout Thanks, done. Glad it worked out. :) Reach out if you have any other Playwright questions.