# Implementing Custom Fixtures using config with new Playwright 0.1101

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

I hope this isn't TL;DR. I really need help with Playwright.

**In short: Does anybody know how to migrate a fixture setup to config with Playwright v.01101? There isn't documentation on how to do this.**

Versions of Playwright/Test prior to v0.1101 enabled customize fixtures that you could override or extend from the Playwright/Test modules. I took advantage of this to implement a page object model (POM). Here is my example fixture:

```
// In tests/fixtures.ts
import { folio as baseFolio } from '@playwright/test'; //now missing in v.0.1101
import { IndexPage } from "../PO/IndexPage";

require('dotenv').config();
const baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL;

// Extend built-in fixtures and declare types for new fixtures
const builder = baseFolio.extend<{ indexPage: IndexPage }>();

// In fixtures.ts
builder.indexPage.init(async ({ page }, runTest) => {
    // get built-in page and wrap with POM
    const indexPage = new IndexPage(page, baseURL);

    // pass this to your test
    runTest(indexPage);
});

// Build and export the modified fixtures
const folio = builder.build();
export const it = folio.it;
export const expect = folio.expect;
export const describe = folio.describe;
```

Here is an example of a test I run with this POM:

```
// In tests/e2e.spec.ts
import { IndexPage } from '../PO/IndexPage';
import { describe, it, expect } from './fixtures'
        
it('EN/FR', async ({ indexPage }) => {
     await indexPage.navigateHome();
     await indexPage.getCurrentLanguage()
     await assertGreetingLanguage(indexPage);
     await indexPage.toggleLanguage();
     await assertGreetingLanguage(indexPage);
});

async function assertGreetingLanguage(indexPage: IndexPage) {
    const lang = await indexPage.getCurrentLanguage();
    const greeting = lang === 'English' ? 'Welcome!' : 'Bienvenue!';
    // console.log(`LANG: ${lang} Greet: ${greeting}`);
    expect(await indexPage.getGreeting()).toBe(greeting);
    // expect(await indexPage.getGreeting()).not.toBe(greeting);
}
```

With v0.1101 though, it seems fixtures aren't supported anymore, [and instead can be setup with a config file](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test#write-a-configuration-file). Of course, [Folio is what implements this config setup](https://github.com/microsoft/folio#writing-a-configuration-file).

Comment: You should post the update as an answer and then accept it - this would help other folks asking the same question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolved. :)**

Playwright got back to me on this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test/issues/242). Here's how it's done. Official documentation coming soon:

```
// config.ts

import { PlaywrightEnv, newTestType, setConfig, TestInfo, reporters, setReporters } from "@playwright/test";
import { IndexPage } from "./PO/IndexPage";


require('dotenv').config();
const baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL;

setConfig({
    testDir: __dirname,  // Search for tests in this directory.
    timeout: 30000,  // Each test is given 30 seconds.
    // timeout: 90000,  // Each test is given 90 seconds.
    retries: 0,  // Failing tests will be retried at most two times.
});

setReporters([
    // Report to the terminal with "line" reporter.
    new reporters.line(),
    // Additionally, output a JUnit XML file.
    new reporters.junit({ outputFile: 'junit.xml', stripANSIControlSequences: true }),
    new reporters.list(),
]);

// Extend the default environment to add any test arguments, for example POMs.
class MyEnv extends PlaywrightEnv {
    async beforeEach(testInfo: TestInfo) {
        // Get all default arguments, including Page.
        const result = await super.beforeEach(testInfo);
        // Create your POM.
        const indexPage = new IndexPage(result.page, baseURL);
        // Return default arguments and new POM.
        return { ...result, indexPage };
    }
}

// Declare "indexPage" test argument for types in IDE.
export const test = newTestType<{ indexPage: IndexPage }>();
export { expect } from "@playwright/test";

// Run tests in three browsers.
const options = {
    // Launch options:
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 50,
    // Context options:
    viewport: { width: 800, height: 600 },
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    // Testing options:
    // video: 'retain-on-failure',
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure'
};

// Run tests in three browsers.
test.runWith(new MyEnv('chromium', options), { tag: 'chromium' });
test.runWith(new MyEnv('firefox', options), { tag: 'firefox' });
test.runWith(new MyEnv('webkit', options), { tag: 'webkit' });
```